# Using a vi-like editor to edit filenames in a directory

Tags: directory, filenames, vi, editing

I often find myself editing the file names in a directory

I used to use vi a lot, and I always liked it

Has anyone adapted vi to facilitate editing filenames?

My thought is it would look like a regular file, but each line would be a file name, and various mv commands would run to change the filenames when saving

Is this crazy? Has anyone done it?

Thanks, Jim

Answer (score 0):

You can *invoke vim on a directory* to start the explorer view which allows you to edit filenames.

Example for a directory named `dir` containing files `file1` and `file2`: Running `vim dir` creates the interactive view as shown below.

```
" ============================================================================
" Netrw Directory Listing                                        (netrw v153)
"   /home/username/dir
"   Sorted by      name
"   Sort sequence: [\/]$,\<core\%(\.\d\+\)\=\>,\.h$,\.c$,\.cpp$,\~\=\*$,*,\.o$,\
"   Quick Help: <F1>:help  -:go up dir  D:delete  R:rename  s:sort-by  x:special
" ==============================================================================
../                                                                             
./
file1
file2
```

Using vim should be feasible for you because you asked for a vi-like editor.

Comment: Thanks!

I've heard of VIM but I'm not familiar with it. Will check it out

Comment: You might already be using vim without knowing about it. Depending on your distribution a stripped down vim might be shipped as vi. Typing _:version_ inside your vi should reveal more.

Answer (score 0):

check the vidir utility, here's the man page https://linux.die.net/man/1/vidir